# how to check the mail functionality in local host server?

Tags: php, email

I am sending email from my localhost There occurs a server error 
    Failed to connect to mailserver at "smtp.bizmail.yahoo.com" port 465, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()
when i host my project to the server my function works 
Now i need a solution such that the mail functionality must work in my localhost too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download miniRelay smtp server from [here](http://netvicious.com/). Use localhost or 127.0.0.1 as smtp server and port 25 to connect to smtp server and send emails.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try setting smtp to "127.0.0.1" and smtp_port to 25. That's assuming your localhost is running sendmail or something similar.